# How to set requirements for word document online only in office add-in manifest

Tags: office-js, office-addins

I want to set the requirements in my office add-in manifest for word online use only. here's what I have:

```
 <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Document" />
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
        <Set Name="Dialog" />
        <Set Name="DocumentEvents" />
        <Set Name="OoxmlCoercion" />
        <Set Name="Selection" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
```

Comment: Please read this tutorial for asking better questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Office add-in for Word desktop only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41869321/office-add-in-for-word-desktop-only)

Answer (score 1):

you cannot do this via the manifest, but you can do a runtime check and provide an error ui by checking Office.context.diagnostics.platform  (it will return OfficeOnline when executed on Online)

Comment: Platform is actually available on context [directly](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/shared/context.md)